# NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is not working from local server

Tags: node.js, linux, nvm

I want to use this NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR env variable on my computer to be able to download node tar.xz from my local server instead of the official dist.

Steps which I did ->

`export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://xx.xx.xx.xx/node-v16.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`

as I saw curl is working fine ->

`curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR --output test.tar.xz % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 21.4M  100 21.4M    0     0  7060k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 7063k`

but when I want to execute "`nvm install v16.18.1`" command it's just failing ->

`Version 'v16.18.1' not found - try nvm ls-remote to browse available versions.`

`nvm ls-remote` indeed is not showing any available node version.

Do you know where I've made mistake so I'm not able to install it from my local server?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to enter the url of the repository, example:

```
export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nexus.org/repository/nodejsversion
```

I use nexus repository, and I have created a proxy type repository named nodejsversion pointing to https://nodejs.org/dist/